# How do I displays errors when saving changes in an ExtJS4 GridPanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, extjs4

If I have a store attached to an Ext.grid.GridPanel, and I return errors from the server, how can I pass information from the response to the user?

So, for example

```
Ext.define('BC.data.Model.DnsZoneFile', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
         { name :'dnsZoneFileId'},
         { name :'origin'},
         { name :'serialNumber', type: 'int', defaultValue: 2011122001},
         { name :'status', defaultValue: 'PENDING_UPLOAD'},
         { name :'clientId', type: 'int', defaultValue: 1},
         { name :'ttl', type: 'int', defaultValue: 120}
    ],
    idProperty: 'dnsZoneFileId',
    idgen: {
        type: 'sequential',
        seed: 1,
        prefix: 'New'
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create : '/dns/zone-file/xhr-put',
            read   : '/dns/zone-file/xhr-get',
            update : '/dns/zone-file/xhr-post',
            destroy: '/dns/zone-file/xhr-delete'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'zoneFiles',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            allowSingle: false
        }
    }
});
```

How can I specify a callback to be handled if the API on `/dns/zone-file/xhr-put` returns an error of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.data.proxy.Ajax only exposes one event called `exception` that is called for all operations; however, the event handler will receive the operation being performed that caused the exception. Therefore, you can look for the `create` operation in the `exception` event handler, as follows:

```
    // ...
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create : '/dns/zone-file/xhr-put',
            read   : '/dns/zone-file/xhr-get',
            update : '/dns/zone-file/xhr-post',
            destroy: '/dns/zone-file/xhr-delete'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'zoneFiles',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            allowSingle: false
        },
        // here is the event handler
        listeners: {
            exception: {
                fn: function (thisProxy, responseObj, operation, eventOpts) {
                    // do error handling for 'create' operation
                    if (operation.action === 'create') {
                        // your code here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
```

Read about [Ext.data.proxy.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-listeners) to see how the proxy `listeners` option and `exception` event work, as well as [Ext.data.Operation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation) to see what is being passed as `operation` in the `exception` event handler.